# Where does $ROS_DISTRO get set?

Tags: catkin, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the directions for [creating an empty catkin workspace](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace), only using hydro in place of groovy.

Most of my environment got set sensibly, except for $ROS_DISTRO:

```
$ env | grep ROS
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/joq/ros/wet/test/src:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://vision-4.local:11311
ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE=/home/joq/.ros/config/rosconsole.config
ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/joq/ros/wet/test
ROS_TEST_RESULTS_DIR=/home/joq/ros/wet/test/build/test_results
ROS_EMAIL=jack.oquin@gmail.com
ROS_DISTRO=groovy
ROS_HOME=/home/joq/.ros
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros
```

I don't know what that breaks, but I suspect it's not good.

It's not getting set explicitly in my **.bashrc**. What should I do to work around this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58379/where-does-$ros_distro-get-set?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS_DISTRO gets set by `roslib`:

https://github.com/ros/ros/blob/groovy-devel/core/roslib/env-hooks/10.ros.sh.em#L9

As `catkin` is ROS agnostic, the responsibility for setting all ROS related environment variables is isolated into environment hooks which live in `roslib` and are picked up by `catkin`. Therefore, a workspace without `roslib` in it will not produce ROS variables.

EDIT:

Sorry, I misread your question, `ROS_DISTRO` should getting set to `hydro`, but we have not update that line in the roslib version for hydro.

I opened a ticket about it here:

https://github.com/ros/ros/issues/10

I jumped to conclusions when I saw "empty workspace", my bad.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-18**:
I figured it was something like that, but could not determine where it is getting set.